# cakephp containable aggregate queries

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In Cake, I'm retrieving a dataset that contains MIN/MAX/SUM/GROUP, but I'm also wanting to pull other tables of related data (containable).  Does that need to be two separate requests or is there a way to structure a single cake request to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to retrive. Can you give some example? Or more details? You can use one of a JOINS methode, or UNION, or subqueries

little example: (it's from cakephp book 2.0 ..)

```
$SubQueryCondition['`User2`.`status`'] = 'B';

$dbo = $this->User->getDataSource();
$subQuery = $dbo->buildStatement(
    array(
        'fields' => array('`User2`.`id`'),
        'table' => $dbo->fullTableName($this->User),
        'alias' => 'User2',
        'limit' => null,
        'offset' => null,
        'joins' => array(),
        'conditions' => $conditionsSubQuery,
        'order' => null,
        'group' => null
    ),
    $this->User
);
$subQuery = ' `User`.`id` NOT IN (' . $subQuery . ') ';
$subQueryExpression = $dbo->expression($subQuery);

$conditions[] = $subQueryExpression;

$this->User->find('all', compact('conditions'));
```